# MVVM ViewModel vs. MVC ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, mvvm, viewmodel

ViewModel is a term that is used in both MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) and the recommended implementation for ASP.NET MVC.  Researching "ViewModel" can be confusing given that each pattern uses the same term.

What are the main differences between the MVC ViewModel and MVVM ViewModel?  For example, I believe the MVVM ViewModel is more rich, given the lack of a Controller.  Is this true?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

A rather challenging question to answer succinctly, but I'll attempt it. (Bear in mind that the answers to these kinds of questions are still the subject of debate amongst developers.)

In MVC, the ViewModel provides all the information necessary for a View to be rendered. The data it contains is created using data defined in the Model. The View reads the ViewModel and renders the output. Input from the View is passed to the Controller, which manipulates the Model, constructs an appropriate ViewModel, and passes this to the View for rendering.

In MVVM, the ViewModel serves the same function as it does in MVC, but it also replaces part of the MVC Controller by providing commands which allow the View to manipulate the Model. WPF databinding manages the updating of the View according to changes in the ViewModel (and this effectively replaces the remaining function of the MVC Controller).

Comment: In practice; the ViewModel in ASP.NET MVC allows for no 'Magic Strings' in the View; and provides a strongly typed model for the view to display (Intellisense included, and all that jazz).  Otherwise, excellent answer.

Comment: Good answer.  @George: You can still use Magic Strings in MVC though... this isn't a concern of MVC... it doesn't do anything to prevent this practice.

Answer (score 8):

It's been a while since I played UI Design Patterns Bingo.. however let me take a stab at this..

MVVM is just something that MS has come up with... because it helps you to get the most out of WPF. You combine the state and behavior of the view into a class (a presentation model) that is easily testable + then you use data-binding to get the data into any view.

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) has a brief of the evolution of MVVM. Combine this with Fowler's "[GUI Architectures](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html)" series, and you should be on your way.

Update: Didn't know there was something called [MVC-VM](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/06/29/how-we-do-mvc-view-models.aspx). Apparently a brainchild of the ASP.NET MVC crowd. Looks and sounds similar to MVVM (except tuned for ASP.NET MVC); the only difference is that it places a restriction that there is 1:1 mapping between VM and View. I'd have guessed 1:N, but everything else matches.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a (way) old question, but I've been pointed to it as an example of using "View Model" in the context of MVC.  I argue that this is incorrect and can lead to confusion by people who are new to either/or/both patterns.  Whoever is doing it--stahp.  Here's why (and it's even an answer to the original question in a roundabout way).

An example of when this happens can be seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27363213/how-to-resolve-arguments-are-not-valid-for-system-componentmodel-propertychangin).  The user is trying to use a View Model that implements INotifyPropertyChanged in an ASP.NET MVC application, thus mashing together desktop and stateless web application design in an architectural fail and heartbreak.

To put it simply, there is no "View Model" in the MVC pattern.  There *is*, however, a functional equivalent, and that's the Controller.  Just to be clear about the parts and their purpouses,

MVVM (desktop applications):

- *Model* - Strongly typed object that holds data to be passed between the View and View Model
- *View* - The UI viewed by the user and through which the user interacts with the system
- *View Model* - Interprets user actions (e.g., via ICommand), performs them, updates application state

MVC (web applications):

- *Model* - Strongly typed* object that holds data to be passed between the View and View Model
- *View* - A UI generator that combines the Model, code and HTML to render a webpage
- *Controller* - Accepts user requests, interprets them, updates application state and uses a View to convert this state into an HTML webpage

**The Model** is practically the same in both patterns.  Desktop models may implement update event notifications, web Models may be dynamic (i.e., not strongly typed), and both may or may not include validation methods or metadata.

**The View** in the desktop is what the user sees.  In the web, it is a generator that outputs HTML for browsers to display on the client side.  It must interpret user interaction on the desktop, but on the web that is handled by client side javascript, the browser, and the requests that are sent back to the server.

**The View Model/Controller** are roughly functionally equivalent, but differ greatly in how they are implemented and how they operate.  **In the View Model**, user interaction with the application is transferred to View Models via ICommands, routed events, and other methods (many MVVM frameworks provide different ways to hook View Models to the UI and other parts of the application).  **In a Controller**, a request comes in with all information needed for the Controller to return a result to the user (assuming it's a 200 OK request).  The Controller must perform whatever work is necessary to create the state (aka Model) needed for the HTML generator (the View) to create the response.  Design-wise, the Controller sits above the View and Model knowing and controlling both, whereas the ViewModel sits next to the View, passing the Model (and other information) between them.

What really seems to confuse some people is that there are *client side MVVM frameworks* that you can mix into your MVC application.  These exist solely in javascript in the user's browser, and have nothing to do with whatever particular pattern you're following on the server side.  You can run a classic ASP website that uses MVVM on the client side.  Hell, you can run static HTML pages that use MVVM on the client side.  They are that separate.

These javascript MVVM frameworks typically follow a similar pattern to the desktop MVVM pattern described above, but adjusted to work more in tune with the nature of the HTML DOM and javascript.  For example, there is no extensive binding system woven into the DOM, and javascript has a very limited type system, so matching up templates to models is much different than in WPF.  They also typically work disconnected from the server, and when they need to interact, prefer AJAX calls rather than POSTing the page back to the Controller (AJAX calls typically are handled by WebAPI Controllers in ASP.NET MVC).

So, to summarize, there really isn't a View Model in MVC.  The Controller is the rough equivalent, but is very different in how it receives user input, interprets it, and returns a result to the user.  Using the term "View Model" to refer to anything in MVC can only lead to confusion, and therefore should be avoided. Use the proper terms for the proper parts of the pattern.  It may seem pedantic, but it should help keep things clear and be less confusing to people who are new to both patterns.

Comment: Sorry but I believe this is incorrect and contributes to the confusion that abounds with VM's and MVC.  Adams answer above is correct in one line: "In MVC, the ViewModel provides all the information necessary for a View to be rendered."  IOW, no part of the VM exists in the controller.  A controller is not a functional equivalent to a VM.  A VM is a single well defined object that has all the properties necessary to render a view.  I explain how to construct them here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc/29135747#29135747

Comment: @Sam So the Controller, like the ViewModel, doesn't interpret user actions, translate them into business logic, and return the results of these actions to Views to render?

Comment: Absolutely not!  The job of a controller is to return a view to a request.  And not one thing more.  Controllers are usually quite small (google "skinny controller").  The job of the VM is entirely different and unrelated to the controller.  The job of the VM is to assemble objects and services into a single object that is than presented to a rendering engine so the view can be created.  The VM contains logic to interact with the user (animate, colorize, hide/show, etc.) and calls business services as necessary on behalf of the view.

Comment: @Sam Please.  It ***only*** returns a View?  And the ViewModel can *animate* elements in the UI?  That's laughable.  Not sure if troll, but certain full of nonsensical absolutes.  I'm done with this convo.  Good day to you, sir.